# Insert from MySQL joined table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drupal, drupal-6

I have two databases named `drupal` and `wordpress`. I try to migrate post image paths from drupal 6 to wp.

Tables `drupal.content_field_image` and `drupal_files` contain necessary data:

`drupal.content_field_image` has field_image_fid - nid pair. `drupal.drupal_files` has fid - filepath pair (field_image_fid = fid).

I need to get the table that contains both nid and filepath, so I join this tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `content_field_image` 
JOIN `files` ON content_field_image.field_image_fid = files.fid;
```

Now I need to insert data to `wordpress` db so that:

`meta_id` = 34 + n (n is increment)

`post_id` = `nid` from joined table

`meta_key` = fifu_image_url

`meta_value` = `filepath` from joined table

So I have some questions:

1. How to make insert from joined table?
2. How to make while-like loop to insert every entry from joined table?
3. How to make n increment by 1 after every insert?

Comment: use "insert from select" query type. ur all the values inserted with each icrement. And you can use joins also. But make sure columns names are same. First try on local, for confimation.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make insert from joined table?

Use a [`INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) construct

> How to make n increment by 1 after every insert?

Declare that column `n` as `auto_increment` column. Else, you will have to do it yourself if your concerned table already has a `auto_increment` column in place.

> How to make while-like loop to insert every entry from joined table

You don't need that at all. `INSERT .. SELECT` construct will insert all the fetched rows to your referred table.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert with select could be something like this:

```
insert into wordpress.table
SELECT (@i:=@i+1), nid, fifu_image_url, filepath
FROM drupal.content_field_image
JOIN drupal.files ON content_field_image.field_image_fid = files.fid;
join (select @i:=34) inc on true
```

To make it work, the columns of your select **must** have the same columns of the table you are inserting.

The incremental int could be made with this variable @i, initialized as 34 like you wanted and incremented 1 by 1 as the results as printed.